# Robot Framework - Are all the images being tested?

Tags: css, image, robotframework

When I use the script "Page Should contain image" or "Element should be visible" and the locator indicates to a set of images by its class, are all of them tested or just the first?

Example:

```
figure class="images"
  image1
  image2
  image3

/figure
```

Then in robot framework I test this script for all the images:

```
${images} = "css=figure.images"
Page should contain image | ${images}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Answer (score 2):

It will pass as soon as it gets a valid match.  You have told it to find an image of a particular class and it has found it, you haven't asked it to find three images or three images of the same class.